Frobenius identity on finite-dimensional Hopf algebras
Let $(H,m_H,e_H,\Delta_H,\epsilon_H)$ be a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, where $m_H$ denotes multiplication, $e_H$ is the unit map, $\Delta_H$ is the comultiplication, and $\epsilon_H$ is the counit map. We will use Sweedler's notation for the comultiplication, writing $\Delta_H(h) = h_{(1)} \otimes h_{(2)}$. Let $(H^*,m_{H^*},e_{H^*},\Delta_{H^*},\epsilon_{H^*})$ be the dual Hopf algebra, with the maps recalled in the Appendix.
According to [LS69, Theorem on page 79], the dual algebra $H^*$ admits a non-degenerate right integral $\lambda$. "Non-degenerate" means that if $\lambda(hk) = 0$ for all $k \in H$, then $h = 0$. A "right integral" satisfies $\lambda(h_{(1)}) h_{(2)} = \lambda(h) 1_H$ for all $h \in H$.
The Frobenius map $\phi: H \to H^*$ is defined by $\phi(h)(k) = \lambda(kh)$. This map is an isomorphism of left $H$-modules, indicating that $H$ and $H^*$ are Frobenius algebras (see [Par71] and [EGNO15, Corollary 6.4.5]). In other words, for the new comultiplication and counit, defined as:
$$
\Delta'_{H^*} := (\phi \otimes \phi) \circ \Delta_H \circ \phi^{-1} \quad \text{and} \quad \epsilon'_{H^*} = \epsilon_H \circ \phi^{-1},
$$
$(H^*,m_{H^*},e_{H^*},\Delta'_{H^*},\epsilon'_{H^*})$ is a Frobenius algebra, in particular, the following Frobenius identities hold:
$$
(\mathrm{id}_{H^*} \otimes m_{H^*}) \circ (\Delta'_{H^*} \otimes \mathrm{id}_{H^*}) = \Delta'_{H^*} \circ m_{H^*} = (m_{H^*} \otimes \mathrm{id}_{H^*}) \circ (\mathrm{id}_{H^*} \otimes \Delta'_{H^*}).
$$
These identities are typically represented diagrammatically as

The equality between the LHS and the RHS can be reformulated as follows. For all $x,y,h,k \in H$,
$$
\lambda(hx_{(1)})\lambda(k_{(1)}x_{(2)})\lambda(k_{(2)}y) = \lambda(h_{(1)}x) \lambda(h_{(2)}y_{(1)})\lambda(ky_{(2)}).
$$
Question: How can we directly prove the above identity?
Here is a proof under the assumption that $h = 1_H$. We will use the right integral identity multiple times.
$$ \lambda(1_Hx_{(1)})\lambda(k_{(1)}x_{(2)})\lambda(k_{(2)}y) =  \lambda(k_{(1)}\lambda(x_{(1)})x_{(2)})\lambda(k_{(2)}y) = $$ $$\lambda(k_{(1)}\lambda(x))\lambda(k_{(2)}y) = \lambda(x) \lambda(\lambda(k_{(1)})k_{(2)}y) = \lambda(x) \lambda(y) \lambda(k) =  $$ $$ \lambda(x) \lambda(k\lambda(y)) = \lambda(x) \lambda(k\lambda(y_{(1)})y_{(2)}) = \lambda(1_Hx) \lambda(1_Hy_{(1)})\lambda(ky_{(2)}). $$
Similarly, assuming that $k = 1_H$, both LHS and RHS simplify to $\lambda(x) \lambda(y) \lambda(h)$.
An element $g \in H$ is called group-like if $\Delta_H(g) = g \otimes g$ and $\epsilon_H(g) = 1$. Then $\lambda(g) = \delta_g := 1$ if $g=1_H$, $0$ otherwise. Assume that $x,y,h,k $ are group-like, then the above identity is trivially true, since it reformuates as follows: $$ \delta_{hx} \delta_{kx} \delta_{ky} = \delta_{hx} \delta_{hy} \delta_{ky}.$$

Appendix: dual Hopf algebra
For all $f,g \in H^*$ and for all $h,k \in H$,
$$(m_{H^*}(f \otimes g))(h) := (f \otimes g)(\Delta_H(h)),$$
$$\Delta_{H^*}(f)(h \otimes k) := f(m_H(h \otimes k)),$$
$$e_{H^*}(1)(h) := \epsilon_{H^*}(h),$$
$$\epsilon_{H^*}(f) := f(e_H(1)).$$
In other words,
$$(fg)(h) = f(h_{(1)})g(h_{(2)}),$$
$$f_{(1)}(h) \otimes f_{(2)}(k) = f(hk),$$
$$1_{H^*}(h) = \epsilon_{H^*}(h),$$
$$\epsilon_{H^*}(f) = f(1_H).$$

References
[EGNO15] Etingof, Pavel; Gelaki, Shlomo; Nikshych, Dmitri; Ostrik, Victor. Tensor categories. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, 205. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2015. xvi+343 pp.
[LS69] Larson, Richard Gustavus; Sweedler, Moss Eisenberg. An associative orthogonal bilinear form for Hopf algebras. Amer. J. Math. 91 (1969), 75--94.
[Par71] Pareigis, Bodo. When Hopf algebras are Frobenius algebras. J. Algebra 18 (1971), 588--596
